# Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Landroid/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager

Tags: android, exception

I compiled app and distribute it to users with `Google Play`. I integrated `Firebase Crash` there and now I see a lot of errors in console.

```
Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager;

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.xxx.yyy/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

I use ProGuard with default settings. Is there anything I can do to fix this?
I compiled it with `Android Studio 2.2 Preview 4`.

Thank you for any help.

---

**EDIT**

I recheck my code and I am ashamed that I asked this : ) Why?

As you suggested, I should check API version, which I did, but because I develop multi-version application (working different way based on API version), I had to "disable" warning about API version.

I made stupid mistake, because I implemented function required API23, before I check, if there is API23.

Is there any better way how to do this, or doing following **if API** is best approach?

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            return true;
        }
else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Whats your targetSdk and minSdk?

Comment: minSdkVersion=16, targetSdkVersion=24

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle to your question?

Comment: @Michal have you find any solution yet. Please give me any hint.

Answer (score 3):

`NetworkStatsManager` [requires API level 23](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/usage/NetworkStatsManager.html). You should actually see a corresponding warning in Android Studio. You should test your app with an emulator or device running the choosen `minSdkVersion` API version and pay attention to warnings shown by the Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using this class somewhere in your code :

```
android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager
```

then add the following to your `proguard-rules.pro` file :

```
-keep class android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager
```

also add `-keep class` rules for other `NoClassDefFoundError`s that you're getting, **or** identify the library which is using this and add their proguard rules.

and as you said you've integrated `Firebase Crash Reporting` in your app, I would recommend you to add the proguard rules for that as well.